# How to run sbt as daemon?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sbt

I've tried `nohup "sbt run" &`

returns : `nohup: failed to run command ‘sbt run’: No such file or directory`

and tried :

```
nohup sbt run &
[2] 7897
# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
```

When I carriage return expecting process to continue running I receive :

```
[2]+  Stopped                 nohup sbt run
```

How to run sbt as a daemon ?

Update :

```
sbt run </dev/null &
[5] 8961
```

I think cd up one dir :

```
# cd ..

[5]+  Stopped                 sbt run < /dev/null  (wd: /home/sum)
(wd now: /home)
```

So it starts as daemon but if I perform any actions such as changing dir it kills the process ? How to keep process running ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like `sbt` requested input from your terminal. If it does not really need input (which is probably the case when you run program in background), you can run it like this:

```
sbt run </dev/null >output-file &
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17626350/1492351) for details.

EDIT

Ok, now that was a puzzle. Short answer: run `sbt` as follows:

```
setsid nohup sbt run &
```

Rationale:

The reason why `sbt` stops is arrival of `SIGTTOU` signal. It is delivered to background process in several cases, which include **modifying terminal configuration**. This is our case because according to `strace -f sbt run &`, `sbt` does a lot of black magic under the hood like this:

```
[pid 16600] execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "stty -g < /dev/tty"], [/* 75 vars */] <unfinished ...>
```

To work this around, you can run `sbt` in a different session to detach it from current terminal, so that it won't open /dev/tty and mess with our terminal.

Comment: @blue-sky Updated.

Answer (score 8):

This should also work

```
sbt -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal run &
```

source: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/701

Answer (score 1):

oleg-andriyanov's answer did not work in my case.
(process exited soon after launch)

In a such case, try Mirko Stocker's command written in play ML below for alternative.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/ZgjrPgib0-8

```
# screen -d -m sbt run
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use tmux to do this (and persist anything else). A bonus feature is that if you install on a remote server you can persist jobs as "sessions" and reconnect to the same terminal "session". https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/persistent-terminal-sessions-with-tmux/

1) Launch your sbt job

```
sbt
run
```

2) detach with tmux session

```
ctrl+b (then release)
d
```

3) Show active tmux sessions (only occurs local tmux)

```
ctrl + b 
s
```

4) Show all sessions on remote machine

```
$ tmux a
```

5) Attach session

```
$ tmux attach-session (your-session-number)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already run sbt and you want to move it to the background then once the processes is in STOPPED condition, send it a CONTINUE signal with

```
kill -s SIGCONT PID
```

or

```
kill -s SIGCONT JOB_NUMBER
```

This will ensure that the sbt process is now running in the background.