# How to run multiple sbt projects in parallel?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, microservices

I have a multi-project sbt build (each project is micro service). 
For development convenience, I want to run all of them at the same time.
Is it possible with sbt?

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(
    serviceA,
    serviceB
  )

lazy val serviceA = (project in file("service-a"))
 ...

 lazy val serviceB = (project in file("service-b"))
 ...
```

I can run them individually with `serviceA/run` or `serviceB/run`

But I need to run serviceA and serviceB with single sbt command (they will be running on different ports)

Comment: Try the `bgRun` task to run in background. to run two tasks at the same time use `all A B` command.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with play framework https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/9505

Comment: we use Ammonite to call multiple sbt commands: http://ammonite.io/#SBTIntegration

Comment: @pme could you please provide some example or give more info?

Comment: @laughedelic where is `all` declared?

Comment: @steinybot you can see its name in the code is [`MultiTaskCommand`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/e1d8f0cafd56bc299e561fbd7823b5a443f07802/main/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/CommandStrings.scala#L23), then it's mentioned [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/e1c7704e6c012cf047fc209fc0ca55908270d9de/main/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/Act.scala#L455), but the further digging for its definition I'll leave to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io)

We us Ammonite scripts (e.g. `runner.sc`) to run sbt. I never used `Future` as we run one thing after the other.

Or use a simple bash file:

Your requirement is more or less running *sbt* in the background.
Here is an according question: [how-to-run-sbt-as-daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643208/how-to-run-sbt-as-daemon)

Taking this to your question, this could look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sbt -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal serviceA/run &
sbt -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal serviceB/run &
```

I couldn't test this, let me know if it works.

Comment: Kinda not working.. I see that both services started, but when I hit endpoints of first via postman it never ends... second service is completely down..